# Humanizer French title case support

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, humanizer

The built in .Net method **TextInfo.ToTitleCase** handles French sentences ok, but there are some samples which cause issues, see [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase#remarks) (copied below):

> Generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to uppercase and the rest of the characters to lowercase. However, this method does not currently provide proper casing to convert a word that is entirely uppercase, such as an acronym. The following table shows the way the method renders several strings.
>
> | Input | Language | Expected result | Actual result |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | war and peace | English | War and Peace | War And Peace |
> | Per anhalter durch die Galaxis | German | Per Anhalter durch die Galaxis | Per Anhalter Durch Die Galaxis |
> | les naufragés d'ythaq | French | Les Naufragés d'Ythaq | Les Naufragés D'ythaq |
>
> As illustrated above, the [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase) method provides an arbitrary casing behavior which is not necessarily linguistically correct. A linguistically correct solution would require additional rules, and the current algorithm is somewhat simpler and faster. We reserve the right to make this API slower in the future.
>
> The current implementation of the [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase) method yields an output string that is the same length as the input string. However, this behavior is not guaranteed and could change in a future implementation.

Is there an option within the Humanizer library to Titleize with a given culture?

Comment: How do you call the method?

Comment: "les naufragés d'ythaq".Titleize ();

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have exactly this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would feel like a good addition to the [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/) library but currently it's not supported.

If I were to implement title casing for French, I'd look at the javascript [titlecase-french](https://github.com/benoitvallon/titlecase-french) library and rewrite it in C#, following the good set of [rules](https://github.com/benoitvallon/titlecase-french#the-rules) it defines:

> There are 5 main rules:
>
> - A title always starts with a word in uppercase
> - A specific list of words are in lowercase
> - After a quote ' words can be in lowercase or uppercase depending of the word before the quote
> - Acronyms are in uppercase
> - Special uppercase letters (with accent for example) are replaced with their simple version

The sample in `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` remarks (*les naufragés d'ythaq*) works as expected with `titlecase-french`:

```js
console.log(require('titlecase-french').convert("les naufragés d'ythaq"));
// Les Naufragés d'Ythaq
```